# Is it possible in Dynamics CRM to run an SQL query like an advanced find and include selection boxes?

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm-2011

In Dynamics CRM-2011 the results of an advanced find are presented as a grid of records, each with a checkbox to select the record for further appropriate actions.  Is it possible to use an SQL-based query to achieve a similar result?

I have implemented a data quality scheme as a business-rules entity, each rule containing the text of an SQL query for reporting records that fail the particular rule.  There is an exceptions report that can run for any selected rule(s) and returns the list of failed records, which can be of any type (rule dependent).  It would be great if instead of running as a report, it ran as a query and displayed the failed records with checkboxes to select them for action.

If anyone has any idea how this might be achieved, I would be grateful for any pointers.

Simon.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your only option is a custom web application.  You could select a business rule, have the application retrieve all entities that fail the rule, and display them in a standard grid from which you can select and perform actions on them.  This application could use CRM styles and be launched within CRM to make it seamless with built in functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I wonder whether you could point me towards a good 'how to' on creating a custom web application?  I've only a couple of months remaining of this contract but it would be interesting to have a go.  From your wording, I am guessing that the app would be visible as an option to a user viewing the business rules grid or detail form, and that the actions available for a selected record in the results grid would be those applicable to the entity type the record came from (so a dynamic reference like the 'Regarding' FK).  Would it sit inside the CRM window?

Comment: Yes, I would put a button on the business rule's ribbon that launches a new page with your result grid, passing the guid of the business rule in the request string. This is the microsoft documentation on creating web applications that connect to CRM
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695790.aspx

This is the method I have previously used for integrating custom web applications with the CRM web app:
http://snataw.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/best-practices-fo-working-with-custom-asp-net-pages-and-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than build a web app and all the plumbing that entails (authentication, hosting, maintenance, etc), another possible option is to build a console app. First, you'd build a relationship between your Rule entity and the entity in question, probably a many-to-many. Then your console app would find the "failed" records and relate them to the Rule record. This console app could be run on a schedule using Task Scheduler on a server.

End result is your users would still be able to use the CRM UI to see all "failed" records by just opening up the Rule record, as well as perform bulk actions on them.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, but I want to retain the mechanism that allows users to select one or more rules and run them immediately from CRM - it helps encourage their ownership of the data.  Also, the target entity of each rule might be different, so I would probably have to use connections to link the rules and failed records - and the link should only exist whilst a record is invalid, so there would be a lot of maintenance of the link records required.