# Create a custom advanced find with sql query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to be able to execute a sql query within crm so that I can interact with results. They are now an SSRS report but I dont want them read-only. I am stumped on how to do this. I found this [Is it possible in Dynamics CRM to run an SQL query like an advanced find and include selection boxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367065/is-it-possible-in-dynamics-crm-to-run-an-sql-query-like-an-advanced-find-and-inc) but I would like some more elaboration. Thanks!

Here is some C# because I thought maybe it has to be a plug in.

```
   public Class1()
   {
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=AAHOASQL;Initial Catalog=DEVAAHOA_MSCRM"))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.BP_GetNearbyContacts", connection))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ZipCode", zipCode);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("GivenMileRadius", givenMileRadius);
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            adapter.Fill(table);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, you could do this with a plugin and some crazy hacking...  The solution would go something like this:

1. Create (or use an existing) Entity that contains the attributes you'd like to return.  CRM Advanced Find will only attributes that are defined.  So if you have additional data you'd like to augment to a CRM entity, you'll need to create the appropriate attributes on the entity to house the data.  You'll only ever use them in the views/advanced finds, but you'll still have to create them, and it will still create fields in the SQL table on the back end.
2. Create an additional column called `SearchSql` that is a boolean, always defaulted to yes, and never placed on forms.
3. Create a plugin that is triggered on the RetrieveMultiple PreEvent that inspects the QueryExpression and determines if the `SearchSql` is marked as yes and stores it in a Shared Plugin Parameter, and then flipping it to false (since all of the data in CRM will have the field marked as false and if you want to return say 10 entities, having that constraint will return 0).
4. Create another plugin that is triggered on the RetrieveMultiple PostEvent.  Have it check for the `SearchSql` Shared Plugin Parameter.  If it is there, then
   you can read the result entities in the plugin context, and use that to run your SQL query.  Then parse the results of your SQL query, and populate the approiate attributes on the related entities.

Comment: hmm I just want to get a few things straight so I understand correctly. When you say values that I'd like to return you mean values from fields right? What do you mean by hydrate the entities? Wouldn't it be just one if I wanted to pull info from Contacts (like in step 1). What do you mean by populate the appropriate ID's? Do you mean the correct Contact ID? Thank you for your answer!!

Comment: @JohnRaesly Just to clarify myself, you want to be able to create an advanced find (or a view) that is pulling data from a SQL SP correct?  I'm assuming you're attempting to augment the CRM Entity data with the results of the SP as well, or is it, you just want to return a single record?

Comment: Yes exactly. I have an sp that finds records within a radius of a starting point and I want to be able to interact with the results in a view or advanced find versus just Read-only like an ssrs report. So return multiple records

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a go!

Answer (score 0):

The way I would implement this is by creating an HTML Web Resource which can be launched from the navigation menu.

This HTML Web Resource will [query CRM using ODATA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx) and the results will be presented in a table make sure your query returns the record's GUID, so you can create a hyperlink which will allow the users to open the record in CRM using [URL Addressable Forms and Views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328483.aspx).

Note that you will need to [get an instance of the CRM context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328541.aspx) inside your HTML Web Resource for your ODATA query and URL Addressable forms. The CRM context will have useful information such as CRM Server, current user in context, CRM Organisation.

Comment: I will look into that...so is using my sproc out of the question?